# relationship between cytokines

Tags: theoretical-biology, infection, pathogenesis, cytokinesis

This is for a mathematical research. I am building a model to identify severe dengue patients through the interaction of cytokines S1P,IL1b,TNFa,PAF and IL10.
For this I would like to know if there are any relationships among these cytokines. That is for example: when PAF increase S1P should decrease. or when IL10 increase Il1b too should increase likewise.
There are seperate articles on the individual effect of these cytokines but I couldn't find any that exhibit any kind of relationship among these cytokines.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you used bad keywords. It is called cytokine (or interleukin) network what you are looking for. There are several articles in the topic.

For example:

- [Cytokine patterns during dengue shock syndrome](http://www.jle.com/en/revues/ecn/e-docs/cytokine_patterns_during_dengue_shock_syndrome__260822/article.phtml?tab=references)
- [Multiplex cytokine profile from dengue patients: MIP-1beta and IFN-gamma as predictive factors for severity](http://www.biomedcentral.com/1471-2334/8/86)

You can find here more:

https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=cytokine+networking+in+dengue

Comment: Thanks for the links. But all they  say it that for example IL1b was depressed and returned to normal or IL1r was significantly elevated in DHF patients. They have findings like that. But what I want is to know if there is any relationship or association **between** the cytokines. Like when  cytokine A increases since it has some kind of ineraction with cytokine B, then the cytokine B too should increase. These kind of relationships do they exist?

Comment: @sam_rox I don't know. I'll check it in the afternoon.

Comment: @sam_rox Sorry, I forgot this question. I think I have found what you need, check this article: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3527385/